# Asp.net C# HtmlTable Placeholder UpdatePanel updating in time before postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, placeholder

I want to programmatically create a table when the user clicks on a button. I have made a program in C# asp.net witch adds a HtmlTable inside a PlaceHolder (that is inside a UpdatePanel) when the action is performed. The problem is that the operation taks a lot of time (there is no database involved) and I want the table to be constructed before postback (I mean to add the rows with the data in time, when it was processed). 
I don't know how this is done, or if it is posible. I don't know Ajax.
I can provide more details on the problem. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery, its quite easy and good to learn.

Super Simple
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/linqed/archive/2009/03/04/generating-html-tables-with-jquery.aspx